# Speed reductions prior to reaching a holding fix

Tags: faa-regulations, aeronautical-information

The instrument ACS states that speed reductions for a hold should be made “3 minutes or LESS” from the holding fix.

While the AIM under 5-1-3 j.8(a) says speed reductions should be made “AT LEAST 3 minutes prior to crossing the holding fix.

Is this just a typo in the FAA documents, or am I just misreading it?

Because starting speed reductions before 3 minutes makes sense because it ensures you are at the right speeds to stay within the “protected airspace” but I’ve been taught the correct procedure is to slow down no sooner than 3 minutes before the holding fix and that is backed by the ACS.

I’m not sure which is the correct procedure or if it really matters all that much, I just have a check ride coming up and I want to be sure I do the correct procedure.

Answer (score 2):

5-3-8-d in the AIM:

> d. When an aircraft is 3 minutes or less from a  clearance limit and a clearance beyond the fix has not  been received, the pilot is expected to start a speed  reduction so that the aircraft will cross the fix,  initially, at or below the maximum holding airspeed

This version seems consistent with ACS guidance.

Later, 5-3-8-j-8-(a) says:

> (a) Speed. When ATC furnishes advance notice of holding, start speed reduction to be at or below the maximum holding speed allowed at least 3 minutes prior to crossing the holding fix. If advance  notice by ATC is not provided, begin speed reduction  as expeditiously as practical.

The nuance here is that the former applies when YOU are *assuming* a self-imposed hold is coming because you are approaching your clearance limit.  The latter applies when your ATC has either directed you to hold, or to expect a hold.

Clarification edit:  I think the idea is that if ATC is about to give you a further clearance on a tightly sequenced leg, they don’t want you slowing down until the last possible moment.  They may have been seconds away from clearing your further, and just falling behind on comms.  But if ATC has already decided you are holding, you might as well not be in a hurry to get into the hold.